# Best way to write SQL Query that checks a column for non-NULL value or NULL

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance

I have a SP with a parameter that has NULL as default value and then I want to do a query like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE a.Blah = @Blah AND (a.VersionId = @VersionId OR (@VersionId IS NULL AND a.VersionId IS NULL));
```

The `WHERE` above checks for both a non-NULL value and a NULL value for `@VersionId`.

Would it be better in terms of performance to instead use an `IF` statement and duplicate the query into one that searches for non-NULL and another for NULL like so? :

```
IF @VersionId IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE a.Blah = @Blah AND a.VersionId IS NULL;
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE a.Blah = @Blah AND a.VersionId = @VersionId;
END
```

Or the query optimizer makes it essentially the same?

**UPDATE:**

(Note: I am using SQL Server)

(And as far as I know, using `a.VersionId = @VersionId` for both cases will not work, will it?)

Comment: Related article: [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)

Comment: I generally use the following: ISNULL(a.VersionId, @VersionId) = @VersionId

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This pattern

```
column = @argument OR (@argument IS NULL AND column IS NULL)
```

can be replaced with

```
EXISTS (SELECT column INTERSECT SELECT @argument)
```

This will let you match a NULL with a NULL and will allow the engine to use an index on `column` efficiently. For an excellent in-depth analysis of this technique, I refer you to Paul White's blog article:

- [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](https://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

As there are two arguments in your particular case, you can use the same matching technique with `@Blah` – that way you will be able to rewrite the entire WHERE clause more or less concisely:

```
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT a.Blah, a.VersionId INTERSECT SELECT @Blah, @VersionId)
```

This will work fast with an index on `(a.Blah, a.VersionId)`.

---

> *Or the query optimizer makes it essentially the same?*

In this case, yes. In all versions (at least) from SQL Server 2005 onward, the optimizer can recognize the pattern `col = @var OR (@var IS NULL AND col IS NULL)` and replace it with the proper `IS` comparison. This does rely on internal rewrite matching, so there may be more complex cases where this is not always reliable.

In versions of SQL Server [from 2008 SP1 CU5 inclusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/grahamk/changed-behaviour-of-option-recompile-syntax-in-sql-server-2008-sp1-cumulative-update-5), you also have the option of using the [Parameter Embedding Optimization](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) via `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, where the runtime value of any parameter or variable is embedded in the query as a literal before compilation.

So, at least to a large extent, in this case the choice is a matter of style, though the `INTERSECT` construction is undeniably compact and elegant.

The following examples show the 'same' execution plan for each variation (literals versus variable references excluded):

```
DECLARE @T AS table
(
    c1 integer NULL,
    c2 integer NULL,
    c3 integer NULL

    UNIQUE CLUSTERED (c1, c2)
);

-- Some data
INSERT @T
    (c1, c2, c3)
SELECT 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3;

-- Filtering conditions
DECLARE 
    @c1 integer,
    @c2 integer;

SELECT
    @c1 = NULL,
    @c2 = NULL;

-- Writing the NULL-handling out explicitly
SELECT * 
FROM @T AS T
WHERE 
(
    T.c1 = @c1
    OR (@c1 IS NULL AND T.c1 IS NULL)
)
AND 
(
    T.c2 = @c2
    OR (@c2 IS NULL AND T.c2 IS NULL)
);

-- Using INTERSECT
SELECT * 
FROM @T AS T
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT T.c1, T.c2 
    INTERSECT 
    SELECT @c1, @c2
);

-- Using separate queries
IF @c1 IS NULL AND @c2 IS NULL
    SELECT * 
    FROM @T AS T
    WHERE T.c1 IS NULL
    AND T.c2 IS NULL
ELSE IF @c1 IS NULL
    SELECT * 
    FROM @T AS T
    WHERE T.c1 IS NULL
    AND T.c2 = @c2
ELSE IF @c2 IS NULL
    SELECT * 
    FROM @T AS T
    WHERE T.c1 = @c1
    AND T.c2 IS NULL
ELSE
    SELECT * 
    FROM @T AS T
    WHERE T.c1 = @c1
    AND T.c2 = @c2;

-- Using OPTION (RECOMPILE)
-- Requires 2008 SP1 CU5 or later
SELECT * 
FROM @T AS T
WHERE 
(
    T.c1 = @c1
    OR (@c1 IS NULL AND T.c1 IS NULL)
)
AND 
(
    T.c2 = @c2
    OR (@c2 IS NULL AND T.c2 IS NULL)
)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```